# How to selectively swallow touches in Kobold2D?

Tags: kobold2d

In my top layer I have a 'Back button' sprite which should receive touches. Normally all other touches should pass through to lower layers, but if this Back button receives a tap gesture then it should swallow the touch.

Currently any touches on the Back button are also being received as touches on the layer beneath.

**Top layer:**

```
-(id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self scheduleUpdate];
        // Initialize KKInput
        KKInput* input = [KKInput sharedInput];
        input.gestureTapEnabled = input.gesturesAvailable;
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

...

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    KKInput* input = [KKInput sharedInput];
    if (input.gestureTapRecognizedThisFrame) {
        CCLOG(@"Top layer tap recognized");
        if ([self.backButton containsPoint:input.gestureTapLocation]) {
            CCLOG(@"Top layer Back Button tap recognized");
        }
    }
}
```

**Lower layer**

```
-(id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self scheduleUpdate];
        // Initialize KKInput
        KKInput* input = [KKInput sharedInput];
        input.gestureTapEnabled = input.gesturesAvailable;
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

...

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    KKInput* input = [KKInput sharedInput];
    if (input.gestureTapRecognizedThisFrame) {
        CCLOG(@"Lower layer tap recognized");
    }
}
```

If I tap somewhere other than the Back button, the output is what I want:

```
2012-10-16 10:58:03.747 MyApp[13838:707] Top layer tap recognized
2012-10-16 10:58:03.749 MyApp[13838:707] Lower layer tap recognized
```

But if I tap on the Back button, the tap isn't swallowed by the button:

```
2012-10-16 10:49:23.426 MyApp[13838:707] Top layer tap recognized
2012-10-16 10:49:23.429 MyApp[13838:707] Top layer Back Button tap recognized
2012-10-16 10:49:23.434 MyApp[13838:707] Lower layer tap recognized
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear the gesture state, you can turn it off and back on again. This should do the trick if you add this where you process the first tap gesture:

```
input.gestureTapEnabled = NO;
input.gestureTapEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. I inserted this just after _CCLOG(@"Top layer Back Button tap recognized");_ but the lower layer still responded to the tap. Perhaps it's too late to disable/enable the gesture at this point?